# CUDA invalid redeclaration of int2

Tags: c++, porting, cuda

I have several .cpp files and a couple of .h files. If I compile them using nvcc instead of g++, everything is fine. Now, when I start (in main.cpp) to allocate memory on the device, i.e

```
cudaMalloc( (void**)&_a, _DSIZE * sizeof(float) )
```

then the problems start. I have tried to change the extension of to .cu, but it is even worst.

Errors that I get:

```
mylib.h(39): error: invalid redeclaration of type name "int2" /usr/local/cuda/bin/../include/vector_types.h(402): here

mylib.h(43): error: invalid redeclaration of type name "int3" /usr/local/cuda/bin/../include/vector_types.h(406): here

mylib.h(47): error: invalid redeclaration of type name "float3" /usr/local/cuda/bin/../include/vector_types.h(434): here
```

Obviously, int2, int3, float3 etc are my own re-declarations which are located in a mylib.h file and are global.

I also get plenty of warnings:

```
mylib.h(128): warning: use of a type with no linkage to declare a function
mylib.h(129): warning: use of a type with no linkage to declare a function
```

What am I doing wrong? I have always been working with .cu files, but I thought that it wasn't really necessary that extension...

Redefined, warnings off but still an error:

/usr/bin/ld: FSPB_kernel_Jelen.o: bad reloc symbol index (0x90 >= 0x1e) for offset 0xa0100 in section `.text'
FSPB_kernel_Jelen.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [FSPB] Error 1

Any idea?

Comment: Please show the declarations/definitions of `int2`, etc.

Comment: typedef struct {

  int x, y;

}int2;



typedef struct {

  int x, y, z;

}int3;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Obviously, int2, int3, float3 etc are my own re-declarations which are located in a mylib.h file and are global.

Looks like CUDA uses those names, and now you have a name collision.  Pick names that aren't taken by the libraries you use, or better yet, use a namespace for your code.  (Best: do both)